# Test interstitial ads is working but real ads is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have developed an android app for the first time and I want to publish it in the play store, but before that, I want to add interstitial ads to it. But when I added the interstitial ads and used the test app ID and the test unit ID the ads are showing properly. But when I change it to my real app ID and unit ID and release the signed APKthe ads is not showing. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will take time to provide ads for new admob user, if test ads working then your implementation is ok. don't worry.